# Bounding a continuously differentiable function using Taylor given the function is bounded by the norm of x

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Suppose $0 < r < 1$ and that $f \colon B_1(0) \to \mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable. If there is an $\alpha > 0$ s.t. $|f(x)<\Vert x\Vert^\alpha$ for all $x \in B_r(0)$, prove there is an $M > 0$ s.t. $|f(x)| \leq M\Vert x\Vert$ for $x \in B_r(0)$.

I tried using a Taylor approximation to bound $|f(x)-f(a)|$, knowing that each is bounded above by $|f(x)<\Vert x\Vert^\alpha$ but this did not work. $F$ is continuously differentiable so all first order partials exist & are continuous, so we can only safely use Taylor for $n=1$. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

(I am assuming that the domain is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

The idea is to show that $f$ is Lipschitz on a compact set containing $B(0,r)$, and use the $\alpha$ bound on $f$ to compute $f(0)$. Combining these gives the result.

> Choose $r' \in (r,1)$, and note that $K=\overline{B}(0,r')$ is compact.
> Hence $M = \sup_{x \in K} \|\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} \|$ is finite.
> Now use the mean value theorem to bound $\|f(x)-f(0)\|$ with $x \in B(0,r)$.
> This gives
> $$\|f(x)-f(0)\| \leq \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \|\frac{\partial f(tx)}{\partial x} \| \|x-0\| \leq M \|x\|$$.
>  By assumption $|f(x)| \leq \|x\|^\alpha$, hence it follows that $f(0) = 0$, and the above estimate gives: $|f(x)| \leq M \|x\|$ for all $ x \in B(0,r)$.

Comment: I meant to add the last two paragraphs as hints, but for the life of me can't remember how...

Comment: OK, I managed, albeit I'm not sure I understand why I had to add so many >!s.